# cygwin pthread_mutex_timedlock surrogate

Tags: c++, cygwin, posix, mutex

Unfortunately the cygwin GCC 4.5.3 pthread library implementation doesn't support the POSIX standard function

```
int pthread_mutex_timedlock(pthread_mutex_t* mutex, struct timespec* abstime);
```

Has anyone a good idea how to implement a good workaround for this method in a mutex wrapper class? May be using `pthread_mutex_trylock()` with a (milliseconds based) `nanosleep()` call?
I don't have a good feeling about the latter idea, but anyway the C++ implementation could look like this:

```
bool MyPosixMutexWrapper::try_lock(const TimeDuration<>& timeout)
{
    if(valid)
    {
        if(timeout == TimeDuration<>::Zero)
        {
             if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutexHandle) == 0)
             {
                 return true;
             }
        }
        else
        {
            struct timespec now;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&now);
            TimeDuration<> tnow(now);
            tnow += timeout;
            struct timespec until = tnow.getNativeValue();
#if defined(_POSIX_TIMEOUTS)
            if(pthread_mutex_timedlock(&mutexHandle,&until) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
#else
            long milliseconds = timeout.milliseconds();
            while(milliseconds > 0)
            {
                 if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutexHandle) == 0)
                 {
                     return true;
                 }

                 struct timespec interval;
                 struct timespec remaining;
                 interval.tv_sec = 0;
                 interval.tv_nsec = 1000000;
                 do
                 {
                     remaining.tv_sec = 0;
                     remaining.tv_nsec = 0;
                     if(nanosleep(&interval,&remaining) < 0)
                     {
                         if(errno == EINTR)
                         {
                             interval.tv_sec = remaining.tv_sec;
                             interval.tv_nsec = remaining.tv_nsec;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             return false;
                         }
                     }
                     clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&now);
                     tnow = TimeDuration<>(now);
                     if(tnow >= TimeDuration(until))
                     {
                          return pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutexHandle) == 0;
                     }
                } while(remaining.tv_sec > 0 || remaining.tv_nsec > 0);
                --milliseconds;
            }
#endif
        }
    }
    return pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutexHandle) == 0;
}
```

Does anyone have a better idea or improvments for this code?

Comment: You could use Windows mutexes instead of pthread mutexes and use `WaitForSingleObject` with an appropriate timeout.  But Windows mutexes are very heavy-handed and require a system call for all cases, even uncontested locking, so in addition to having to write all new code to deal with them, you might take a performance hit.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: I would prefer a somewhat 'POSIX compatible' implementation, the `_POSIX_TIMEOUTS` indicates if the `pthread_mutex_timedlock()` function is available or not. I don't want a windows native solution in this code.

Comment: As I was already afraid, the proposed implementation doesn't work well in Cygwin environment. Despite I have improved the code to check the timeout ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a `pthread_cond_timedwait` to mimic your timed lock. The trick here is that `timed_mutex_` is never held for very long, since waiting on `timed_cond_` releases the lock. `timed_mutex_` is also released immediately after `locked_` is set or unset.

```
struct MutexGuard {
    pthread_mutex_t &mutex_;
    MutexGuard (pthread_mutex_t &m) : mutex_(m) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    }
    ~MutexGuard () {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
    }
};

struct TimedMutex {
    pthread_mutex_t timed_mutex_;
    pthread_cond_t timed_cond_;
    bool locked_;

    TimedMutex ()
        : timed_mutex_(), timed_cond_(), locked_(false) {
        pthread_mutex_init(&timed_mutex_, 0);
        pthread_cond_init(&timed_cond_, 0);
    }

    ~TimedMutex () {
        pthread_cond_destroy(&timed_cond_);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&timed_mutex_);
    }

    int lock (const struct timespec *t) {
        MutexGuard g(timed_mutex_);
        while (locked_) {
            int r = pthread_cond_timedwait(&timed_cond_, &timed_mutex_, t);
            if (r < 0) return r;
        }
        locked_ = true;
        return 0;
    }

    void lock () {
        MutexGuard g(timed_mutex_);
        while (locked_) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&timed_cond_, &timed_mutex_);
        }
        locked_ = true;
    }

    void unlock () {
        MutexGuard g(timed_mutex_);
        locked_ = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&timed_cond_);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thx, your answer looks very promising. Just for curiosity: Is this the reason the cx11 standard provides separate types for mutex and timedmutex? Because the latter might need additional resources for it's implementation?

Comment: @g-makulik: I am afraid I do not know the rationales behind the decisions of the C++11 committee. But, I imagine it allows both a programmer to include a smaller set of code from the library to get a job done, and a library writer to provide the tightest implementation that provides the functionality.

Comment: I don't see why you would use two different mutexes here, the straight-forward solution would be to build your own timed-mutex type by using ONE mutex and one condition-variable. Also this solution is probably going to be really slow when contended.

Comment: @PaulGroke: You have to be holding a mutex to wait on a condition variable. If you already have the mutex you don't need to wait. If you can't get the mutex, then you are not allowed to wait. Hence, the second mutex. Regards

Comment: @user315052: This isn't different from a bounded queue or really anything else you can do with a mutex + condition-variable. Just replace the second mutex by a bool.

Comment: @PaulGroke: I realized this just this morning, and was working on it just now. Thanks for the insight. Regards

Comment: @user315052: Arrr, dammit, I just posted an answer with the "bool" version - seems I was too slow :)

Comment: @PaulGroke: Good point, the edited solution uses less ressources.

Comment: Sorry to resuscitate this old 'resolved' thread, but I would **really** appreciate advice regarding how to actually put this into effect.  How do I get cygwin / g++ setup to see this implementation so I could compile a simple program that referenced `std::thread`?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps: cygwin g++ 4.5.3 doesn't support `std::thread`.

Comment: That's absolutely correct -- and when you start digging and finally nail it down, the reason why cygwin does not support `std::thread` is because `pthread_mutex_lock` is not implemented.  See this thread http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-04/msg00689.html for details.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps: Since cygwin compiles their version of g++ without `std::thread` support, a consequence is that the libstdc++ library that is supplied on cygwin does not provide all the symbols needed even if you manually tried to activate the support with the proper `#define`s.