# mutexes - Timed locking

Tags: c, linux, mutex

I want to lock a mutex but fail if a timeout expires. Also I don't want to wait much more after the timeout.

I know what you are thinking. `pthread_mutex_timedlock`. But if the system clock is changed while it is blocking (e.g. if someone runs `date --set` during the timeout) it can wait for years after (currently up to 44) the timeout should have expired.

Comment: It was hard for me to understand what you meant by "given good timing" so I have edited your question.  I hope I have not changed the meaning.

Comment: A sysadmin which changes the `date` by a large amount is doing wrong if he does not reboot the system. A good sysadmin would have installed an NTP client and *never* runs `date --set`

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch: There is no reason to assume anyone is good or doing anything right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the limitation of `pthread_mutex_timedlock()`. It's clock is always based on the wall-clock time.

However, this is not true of `pthread_cond_timedwait()`. You can modify the attribute of a condition variable so that it uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (by using `pthread_condattr_setclock()`). Your timed lock would actually turn into a timed wait.

To implement your own version of a timed lock using a timed wait on a condition variable, you can use a technique similar to that described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11254055/315052).