# use condition variable instead of lock_guard

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I have a simple program in which I want to output the numbers 1-100, with one thread outputting all the odd numbers and the other one all even numbers. Using lock_guard, this is quite an easy task. Code follows:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

std::mutex m;


void print_numbers(int i)
{
    for (i; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(print_numbers, 0);
    std::thread t2(print_numbers, 1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, how can I use condition variables to do this, and perhaps make it a little more elegant?

Comment: A simple `std::mutex` (and `std::lock_guard` along) and a `std::condition_variable` are somehow _orthogonal_ concepts. In fact a `std::condition_variable` actually requires to use at least 2 mutexes, so it's arguable if that's _more elegant_. You use condition variables, to wake up threads for state changes, thus these are similar to semaphores, I don't see how your code actually needs such.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Still however, for the sake of learning only, would you propose a way for using two mutexes with condition variable to achieve the same result?

Comment: Well, you don't even need a `std::mutex` for your code sample, the 2 threads are operating completely independent on a copy of `i`, changes won't ever interfere, or be prone for race conditions. Your `std:mutex m;` is bogus and not needed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How does using `std:condition_variable` require the use of at least 2 mutexes?

Comment: @Hasturkun You may be correct, [here's an old post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194102/cygwin-pthread-mutex-timedlock-surrogate)  that could prove I somehow have a misconception about this.

Comment: @lason When you start a question with "I want to" many SO users will read that as your end-goal. I suspect you're just fielding an example to outline your question. Unfortunately, SO users will try and help you achieve your stated goal. I would reword your question...

Comment: Generally, condition variables are useful when you have multiple consumers of a shared resource such as workers removing items from a queue and there are two separate considerations: whether the resource might be in an interesting state for the consumers and whether or not someone is considering it.

Your mutex is there to protect access to `std::cout` which is definitely not a use case for a condition variable. On the other hand, your desire to implement ordered processing - while not described in the example - might lead to a use case for a condition variable but might lead to a redesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sharing whatsoever in your code. Each thread has a local variable i. A POSIX condition is used for inter-thread communication/signaling. The idea is simple:

1. a thread check a boolean predicates (depending on a shared state) and decide to "wait" when the predicate is false (pthread_cond_wait in POSIX)
2. another thread can modify the shared state and therefore impact the value of the boolean predicate. If this thread changes the state, it can notify the other thread (Thread #1) that it should wake up and re-check its predicate whose value might have now changed (pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_broadcast in POSIX).

Since there is a shared state, you *still* need a mutex to protect that shared state and "lock it" when you are modifying or accessing it.

The typical use case of a POSIX condition is a shared queue. A consumer wishes to "consumes" data items from the queue and, to do so, must wait on a boolean predicate [the queue is non-empty]. The producer generates data items that it deposits in the shared queue. As it adds items, it should notify any "waiters" that they should recheck.

**Bottom line:** conditions are not helpful here. You don't even need mutexes in your example. And conditions must be used with a mutex anyway (the call to pthread_cond_wait takes as input the address of a mutex to atomically release the lock and sleep on the condition). mutex are for *mutual exclusion*. Conditions are meant for *signaling*. Two very different purposes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong of course Laurent Michel, @πάνταῥεῖ . I don't care about i at all. The shared resource between the threads here is cout. If i DON'T use a mutex here, I get bogus output, all even numbers first and all odd after. In order to print all numbers consecutively, I kind of need a mutex actually.

Comment: Your code *suggests* you are caring about `i` because you increment `i` inside the lock_guard. Only do what you absolutely must inside a lock.

Comment: @lason:  my assumption is that the cout is for debugging. Yes, printing must be synchronized, but that's also mutual exclusion. This does not change the nature of the response: conditions are not meant to solve mutual exclusions. They are designed to help with signaling.